# Xaml trigger on a TextBox, bound to a MVVM property not triggering

Tags: c#, xaml, datatrigger

I am a noob at Xaml triggers.
Do you see any obvious reason why this trigger does not work:

```
 <TextBox  Text="{Binding TiretNom}" Margin="1">
    <TextBox.Style>
         <Style>
              <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TiretNom}" Value="">
                     <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Tomato"/>
                      </DataTrigger>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TiretNom}" Value="a">
                        <Setter Property="TextBox.BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                      </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
     </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Neither does the backround change when the property TiretNom = "",
nor does the borderbrush gets red if TiretNom = "a"

Thx in advance.

Comment: Two things to check, first does setting the TextBox binding to `{Binding TiretNom, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}` fix your issue? If not check to make sure your data context is raising property changed notifications. If that doesn't make sense please post the code where your properties are.

Comment: Try to set UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged for each Binding inside DataTrigger.

Comment: That worked guys. Thx a lot. Feel free to put it as an answer if either of you cares about the "good answer" flag.
Also:       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TiretNom}" Value="">
Did not work as startup as the default string property value seems to be null and not "".